# Iphone questionnaire App

Tags: iphone, mobile

Im Try to make an Iphone questionnaire app... something to make test but im a beginner on Iphone Sdk and Objective-C so i would like to take any suggestions

-thanks

Answer (score 1):

Get yourself a copy of [Beginning iPhone Development](http://apress.com/book/view/1430216263)